# elasticsearch sort by subtracting of two numeric fields

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to sort the result by subtraction between two fields?

E.g. There are two fields: "price", "lastPrice". I would sort documents by price - lastPrice.

Can this be done directly or the only way to do is to create a new field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use script sort

**Data:**

```
[
      {
        "_index" : "index19",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "LI9zpnEB1jFeu7E5l58r",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "a",
          "price" : 10,
          "lastPrice" : 15
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index19",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "LY9zpnEB1jFeu7E5xJ_A",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "b",
          "price" : 15,
          "lastPrice" : 20
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index19",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Lo95pnEB1jFeu7E5Sp9w",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "b",
          "price" : 20,
          "lastPrice" : 21
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Query:**

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
        "type": "number",
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "source": "doc['lastPrice'].value-doc['price'].value"
        },
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Result:**

```
[
      {
        "_index" : "index19",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Lo95pnEB1jFeu7E5Sp9w",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "b",
          "price" : 20,
          "lastPrice" : 21
        },
        "sort" : [
          1.0
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index19",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "LI9zpnEB1jFeu7E5l58r",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "a",
          "price" : 10,
          "lastPrice" : 15
        },
        "sort" : [
          5.0
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index19",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "LY9zpnEB1jFeu7E5xJ_A",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "b",
          "price" : 15,
          "lastPrice" : 20
        },
        "sort" : [
          5.0
        ]
      }
    ]
```